# How can I print the Animation Pane of Powerpoint 2010

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a Powerpoint 2010 slide with hundreds of animations.
How can I get a print of the Animation Pane

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not from within PowerPoint. I would use a screen capture instead, like Snagit. It has a scrolling capture that can be used to create a screenshot while scrolling through content. A demo of that technique is in this Techsmith training video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aW-CbfWg_T8&list=PLDyDYqoIde4D1bCC5op3qN4gDLo4xBxQi&index=10

If you don't own Snagit, you can download a 15 day free trial at the Techsmith web site. https://www.techsmith.com/download/snagit/

I'm not affiliated with Techsmith, but I have been using Snagit for years and can recommend it.

Comment: Why would you recommend paid third party software for screenshots, when the Snipping Tool (Win7 and 10) and Snip & Sketch (Win10 only) are pre-installed on Windows?

Comment: @udlp Because it can do screenshots while scrolling. Snipping tool can't do that. With Snagit you can set the capture area to the animation pane, start the capture, then scroll the animation pane all the way down and end up with one screenshot that has it all.